# What is the recommended procedure to evaluate a function when it has embedded another one using inverse function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The problem states the following:

$\textrm{Given:}$

$$\phi\left( 2x+1\right)=6x-10$$
$$\phi\left(f\left(x\right)-3\right)=3x-4$$

$\textrm{Find:}$
$f\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)$

The problem lies in the fact that the function $f\left(x\right)$ is embedded into $\phi$ (nested) and therefore it cannot be worked out in a straight manner. So I thought that the key to solve this would be to use inverse function so I could use then what is inner and solve a two equation system.

By following that route I went this way:

$\phi\left( 2x+1\right)=6x-10$

$\phi^{-1}\left(\phi\left( 2x+1\right)\right)=\phi^{-1}\left(6x-10\right)$

$2x+1= \frac{y+10}{6}$

$12x+6-10=y$

$y=12x-4$

Then going with the second function which has embedded the $f\left(x\right)$:

$\phi^{-1}\left(\phi\left(f\left(x\right)-3\right)\right)=\phi^{-1}\left(3x-4\right)$

$f\left(x\right)-3=\frac{y+4}{3}$

$f\left(x\right)=\frac{y+4}{3}+3$

Then all what would be left to do is to replace the y into the above equation, isn't it?

So I found:

$f\left(x\right)=\frac{(12x-4)+4}{3}+3=4x+3$

Then by inserting the value which is to be "evaluated" in the function would make it into:

$f\left(-\frac{1}{6})\right)=4\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)+3=-\frac{2}{3}+3=\frac{7}{3}$

Therefore the answer would be $\frac{7}{3}$, however this does not appear within the alternatives in my book; to which given are: $37/6$, $35/4$, $35/6$, $37/4$, $-35/6$.

Could it be that Am I misinterpreting something or using the inverse function not properly?. I'd like someone could help me with this as I'm confused on which way should be recommended to solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: How do we know $\phi$ is invertible?

Comment: @JohnDouma $x \mapsto 2x+1$ is a bijection, as is $x \mapsto 6x-10$.  Hence so is $\phi$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\phi\left( 2x+1\right)=6x-10$$
$$\phi\left(f\left(x\right)-3\right)=3x-4$$

We have

$$\phi\left(f\left(\frac{-1}{6}\right)-3\right)=-\frac12-4=-\frac92$$

$$\phi(2x+1)=6x-10=3(2x+1)-13$$

$$\phi(x)=3x-13$$

Hence $$3\left( f\left( -\frac16\right)-3\right)-13=-\frac92$$

$$3 f\left( -\frac16\right)-13=\frac92$$

$$ f\left( -\frac16\right)=\frac13\left(\frac92+13\right)$$

Comment: This method is more straightforward and I was kind of confused at why did you evaluated $-\frac{1}{6}$ at the beginning? but it was just turn out to obtain the $\phi(x)$ function thus this can be evaluated in a second step. Clever but it took me a day to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $u=2x+1$. Then $x=\frac{u-1}2$. That means that $\phi(u
)=\phi(2x+1)=6x-10=6\left(\frac{u-1}2\right)-10=3u-13$. Therefore, $\phi^{-1}(u) = \frac{u+13}3$. From here, just apply $\phi^{-1}$ to boths sides and solve for $f(x)$.

EDIT: Here's applying $\phi^{-1}$ to both sides. $\phi(f(x)-3)=3x-4$ and so $\phi^-1(\phi(f(x)-3))=\phi^{-1}(3x-4)$. That means that $f(x)-3=\phi^{-1}(3x-4)$.
 However, $\phi^{-1}(u)=\frac{u+13}3$ and so $\phi^{-1}(3x-4)=\frac{(3x-4)+13}3=\frac{3x+9}3$. As such, $f(x) - 3 = \frac{3x+9}3$ and so $f(x)=\frac{3x+9}3 + 3$. The rest is simply substituting $-\frac 1 6$ in.

Comment: How do you know that $\phi$ is invertible?

Comment: @JohnDouma $\phi$ is simply one-to-one and onto as if $6x-10=6y-10$ then $x=y$ and if $y$ is a real number $\phi(\frac{y+13}{3})=y$. Therefore, $\phi$ is invertible.

Comment: @memerson I'm still stuck at what you mean from applying $\phi^{-1}$ to both sides. Which sides do you refer to?. Can you include that step in your answer please?. Do you mean that $\phi^{-1}\left(3x-4\right)=3\left(f\left(x\right)-3\right)-4$?. Because of this reason I'd like you could include a clarification.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell, does the edit explain it?

Comment: @memerson Thanks! but I want to know why $\phi^{-1}\left(u\right)=\frac{u+13}{3}$ and not just $\phi\left(u\right)=\frac{u+13}{3}$?. From the looks of it, seems like a change of variable and nothing else. I know this is the premise of inverse function (as means of obtaining the $x$ in terms of the other variable). But does it mean that when you do that it renders a function which is the inverse and the reason why you used the $\phi^{-1}$? This part is where I'm stuck at. The rest which have you added is similar to what I also reached. Hope you can help me clear these doubts.

Comment: @memerson I did sent you a message earlier mind checking it? Since my previous comment seems yet unsanswered. :-(

Answer (score 0):

$\phi(f(x)−3)=3x−4$

$\phi(f(\frac{-1}{6})−3)=3\times\frac{-1}{6}−4=\frac{-9}{2}$

$\phi(2x+1)=6x−10$

$\phi(2\times(\frac{f(x)}{2}-2)+1)=6\times(\frac{f(x)}{2}-2)−10$

$\phi(f(x)-3)=6\times(\frac{f(x)}{2}-2)−10$

Therefore, $\phi(f(\frac{-1}{6})−3)=6\times(\frac{f(\frac{-1}{6})}{2}-2)−10 = \frac{-9}{2}$

$3\times f(\frac{-1}{6})-12-10=\frac{-9}{2}$

$f(\frac{-1}{6})=\frac{35}{6}$

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}
\phi(2x+1) &= 6x-10\\
&= 6\bigg(\frac{2x+1-1}{2}\bigg)-10\\
&= 3\bigg((2x+1)-1\bigg)-10\\
&= 3(2x+1)-3-10\\
&= 3(2x+1)-13\\
\end{align}$

Which implies that $\phi(t) = 3t-13$

$\begin{align}
\phi(f(x)-3) &= 3x-4\\
3(f(x)-3)-13 &= 3x-4\\
3(f(x)-3) &= (3x-4)+13\\
f(x)-3 &= \frac{(3x-4)+13}{3}\\
f(x) &= \frac{(3x-4)+13}{3} + 3\\
f(x) &= x+6\\
\end{align}$

Substituting we have
$f(-\frac{1}{6}) = -\frac{1}{6}+6 = \frac{35}{6}$

Comment: Neat!. The latter part where you introduce a new variable $t$ makes sense for the function $\phi(t)$ however this isn't it the inverse function?.

Comment: No it isn't. I never actually solve for the inverse explicitly, but if you notice, all of the operations implied in the inverse function are used to solve for $f(x)$ [e.g. add 13 and divide by 3]. I updated my answer to reflect this more clearly. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As you mentioned, the inverse function is not used explicitly. Probably this is the reason why I took some time to figure out where did it appears $6\left(\frac{2x+1-1}{2}\right)$ seems that when you do that you obtain the original equation. Needless to say from that on the rest is obvious. I mean to input the resulting expression as $t$. Thanks for sharing your method by the way!. :-)